# How to modify app permissions on a rooted device without third party?

Tags: root-access, permissions

Is there any way to modify app permissions on a rooted (running Android 4.3) device "by hand"?

Or maybe I should ask how third party apps (like "access denied" or "Gemini") can block app permissions?

Comment: What device and Android version are you on?

Comment: It's a Samsung Galaxy note 2014 with Android 4.3.

Comment: Try root explorer app search the apk and long press on the app click permission change your permission

Comment: That's not really non-third party and I'm talking about _installed_ apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use adb (Android Debug Bridge) tools.

-Install platform-tools which are included in Android SDK
-Toggle USB Debugging options on your phone.
-Connect to your phone with adb.

Example operation for testfile.txt

Upload your file with 'adb push ' command.

```
adb push testfile.txt /data/local/tmp/
```

Get shell with 'adb shell' command.

```
adb shell
```

(You will get a prompt like below.)

Become superuser with 'su' command.

```
shell$ su
```

Change permissions of testfile.txt to 644 (-rwx--r--r-)

```
chmod 644 /data/local/tmp/testfile.txt
```